How to solve cloud flare NS records missing
After renewing my domain it is not working and gets errors from DNS records.
When I used intoDNS.com for NSLOOKUP, I got following errors:
Error   **DNS servers responded**   ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
108.162.194.245 172.64.33.118

**Multiple Nameservers**    ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 nameservers is also ok by me.
**Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers**    You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are missing, so here it is again:

ns1.ns.cloudflare.com.
ns2.ns.cloudflare.com.
**SOA record**: No valid SOA record came back!
**MX    Error**:    MX Records  Oh well, I did not detect any MX records so you probably don't have any and if you know you should have then they may be missing at your nameservers!
WWW Error   
**WWW A Record**:   ERROR: I could not get any A records for www.vitaepharma.af!

(I only do a cache request, if you recently added a WWW A record, it might not show up here.)

